# What is the difference between -p and -q options

Tags: jmeter

We have decided to split our jmeter properties into 2 files. One contains more "environment" related variables and the other contains more application centric (stuffs that changes with version).

Everything seems to work fine when using "jmeter.sh -q file1 -q file2 -t test.jmx". However we found there was also a -p option. In which context should it be use (vs the -q?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

```
-p, --propfile {argument}
    the jmeter property file to use
-q, --addprop {argument}
    additional property file(s)
```

this is, using -p you overwrite jmeter.properties, using -q adds a custom properties file.

Comment: I couldn't get around to understand the difference. But I do get it now, the jmeter.properties is a global configuration of jmeter behavior and overriden via -p. The -q is made for purpose like the one we have, which is for properties used inside a test...